# Redux returning undefined promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, frontend, prop

I am stuck trying to figure out Redux. Currently all my "painting" prop is a promise with undefined value:

In page component:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  this.props.setPaintingToProps(paintingId);
}
```

...

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    painting: state
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {    
    setPaintingToProps: paintingId => {
      dispatch({ type: "SET_PAINTING", id: paintingId });
    }
  };
};
```

And In reducer:

```
case "SET_PAINTING":
  paintingService.getDetails(action.id).then(data=>{
    return {...state,
      ...data}
})
break;
```

The reducer method runs and the `data` is correct, but in state it is `Promise {<resolved>: undefined}`.

Thank you in advance, if there is any more info needed to solve this please ask.

Comment: `then(data=>{ return}` will return to callback function. You need add to also add return before `paintingService.getDetails()` i:e `return paintingService.getDetails()`.

Comment: Yes, that part was not my closest try. Now it looks like this but it is still a resolved promise (with the correct data).

setPaintingToProps: paintingId => {
      return paintingService.getDetails(paintingId).then(sauce => {
        dispatch(actions.setPaintingToProps(sauce));
      });
    }

Answer (score 0):

You should use middleware for async call for example redux-thunk to create async action and then dispatch your data

```
export const setPaintingToProps = (paintingId) =>
  (dispatch) => {
    paintingService.getDetails(paintingId).then(data => {
      dispatch({ type: "SET_PAINTING", payload: data });
    })
  };

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {    
    setPaintingToProps: paintingId => dispatch(setPaintingToProps(paintingId));
    }
  };
};

case "SET_PAINTING":
    return {...state,
      action.payload}
})
break;
```

let me know if it works for you

Comment: The setPaintingToProps action throws an error "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions." I installed the middleware, though: const store = createStore(
  paintingsReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk) &&
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

Comment: are you sure your setPaintingToProps  action return a function?

Comment: I will have to take a further look into Thunk, because I could not get through that error yet.
My last attempt: 
`const setPaintingToProps = paintingId => {
  paintingService.getDetails(paintingId).then(data => {
    return { type: "SET_PAINTING", payload: data };
  });
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    setPaintingToProps: paintingId => dispatch(setPaintingToProps(paintingId))
  };
};`

Comment: What middleware did you install ?

Comment: I installed thunk, `createStore(reducer,applyMiddleware(thunk))`, but still I have the error "Actions must be plain objects" when I try to return the function

Comment: wrap it with try catch:


export const setPaintingToProps = (paintingId) => {
try {
  return (dispatch) => {
    paintingService.getDetails(paintingId).then(data => {
      dispatch({ type: "SET_PAINTING", payload: data });
    })
  } catch(error) { console.log(error) }
  };

Comment: The error message said dispatch is not defined. However, I think I had the wrong approach to Redux and since I've been stuck for long I tried to take a simpler approach: getting the data in componentDidMount and then sending it to Redux instead of handling asynchronous functions in it. The thing is in the reducer I return action.payload, which is exactly the object want, but in mapStateToProps `state` argument comes in promisified.

Comment: @ifrances can you post your reducer?